# Where is HttpContext.Timestamp in ASP.NET Core MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I would like to get the initial timestamp of the current HTTP request in an ASP.NET Core MVC controller.
This timestamp used to be accessible (pre ASP.NET Core) by [HttpContext.Timestamp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.timestamp), but Timestamp doesn't seem to be a property of HttpContext anymore.

Where is this property moved to? Or - when it is no longer available - how can I get the timestamp of the HTTP request?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `DateTime.Now` (or `DateTime.UtcNow`)?

Comment: @DavidG: What if the request was received some time ago?

Comment: @SLaks Take the measurement early on and pass it round as required I guess. May not be as accurate, which is why I'm asking if OP can use that instead.

Comment: @DavidG: I would like to know the elapsed time between the actual start of the HTTP request and DateTime.UtcNow in the controller. When the client has a slow network connection and uploads a large file to a controller, there would be a significant difference between the two I suppose?

Comment: @Igor: where would you capture the start of the request?

Comment: Hmm interesting question, I'm not sure if you can get the timestamp of when the request started. Perhaps a custom middleware component could add the data to the request? Should only be a few lines of code to test it.

Comment: You can add middleware into the pipeline. Call `app.Use()`, don't invoke next, and you can do something like `HttpContext.Items.Add("Timestamp", DateTime.Now);` Then inside your controller you can do `var ts = (DateTime)HttpContext.Items["Timestamp"];` It's important you place the middleware at the top of the stack inside Configure.

Comment: @StephenVernyi Basically what I said, but does the pipeline start after the data has been posted or after the first byte arrives?

Comment: [From Microsoft's image](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/_static/request-delegate-pipeline.png), it looks like you can get the request before _anything_ has touched it. This makes sense when you think that applications are self-hosted via Kestrel, and there is no overarching beast like IIS trying to process requests for you.

Comment: @StephenVernyi That image doesn't say when the pipeline does anything, but I would hope it works like my answer. I won't be able to test this until tomorrow unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, I also thought about writing some custom middleware code, but thought this was only executed after the data was already fully received. I'll test this option and let you know.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can add your own middleware to the pipeline which adds additional data to the request. For example:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    //Make sure this code is placed at the very start to ensure it 
    //executes as soon as possible
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        context.Items.Add("RequestStartedOn", DateTime.UtcNow);
        await next();
    };

    //The rest of your code here...
}
```

Then later on in the pipeline:

```
var requestStartedOn = (DateTime)httpContext.Items["RequestStartedOn"];
```

As an aside, if you intend to reuse this code elsewhere, I would put it in it's own library. For example:

```
public class RequestTimestampMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public RequestTimestampMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Items.Add("RequestStartedOn", DateTime.UtcNow);

        // Call the next delegate/middleware in the pipeline
        return this._next(context);
    }
}
```

And then add an extension method to make it easy to use:

```
public static class RequestTimestampMiddlewareExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UseRequestTimestamp(this IApplicationBuilder builder)
    {
        return builder.UseMiddleware<RequestTimestampMiddleware>();
    }
}
```

Now your `Configure` method will look a lot nicer:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRequestTimestamp();

    //The rest of your code here...
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is working. Just a small note: make sure your controller accepts the data you're posting as a parameter, otherwise the controller will be called before the body is fully sent to the server and you will be chasing ghosts :)

Comment: Excellent, I've updated the post to be proper "middleware" and reusable. :)